# HTML table with Php for each loop

Tags: php, html, foreach

Hi, I want to display two columns "test case" and "Test command" in the web.
I am getting "test case" and "test command" values from XML.
But I am facing alignment problem be of some text, case names are lengthy hence I used the table format, but this is not displaying as expected in foreach loop.

```
 <?php
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <th>test cases </th>";
    echo "  <th>test command </th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($listfiles as $filename) {

        $element=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName('netfn')->item(0)->nodeValue ;
        $testcase_Command=$objDOM->getElementsByTagName('Command')->item(0)->nodeValue ;
        $tcname = substr(strstr(basename($fname),'.',true),3);
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='Testcases[]' title= >$tcname" ; // prints test case name 
        //echo "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; $testcase_Command"; // this works but space problem, so adding coloumn below
        echo "<td>$testcase_Command</td>"; // print in the column
        echo "<br />";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo " </table>";
?>
```

I think logic is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: your logic may be good, but your HTML strings are wrong. Check your HTML output, you should quickly see what's wrong :-)

Comment: echo "<input type='checkbox' name='Testcases[]' title= >$tcname" ;
isnt this wrong? where are the <td></td> here?

Comment: also echo "<br />"; should not be there

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it sorry for my mistake .. 
If any one need this might help

```
foreach(){
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<input id='Checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='Testcases[]' value='hii' title= >$tcname" ;  
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "$testcase_Command";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```